# Is there a way to convert a Django project with postgresql database built from source with cube extension into a msi?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, iis

I created a Django project and distributed on IIS that uses PostgreSQL as database. I compiled PostgreSQL from source with a modification on creating an extension.

It is running quite well in IIS but I just want to convert all Django project to be a MSI in order to be able to distributing on others windows PC.

So please anyone advise a way or solution that can help me on this. It would be highly appreciated for your help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Options for distributing your Python application](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/options-distributing-your-python-application-minni-ang).   This article will useful to you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks Jason Pan for your suggestion! I just dive into it and try to apply with compiling PostgreSQL. Minni Ang just mentions the way with precompiled postgresql django I think so. My compiled postgresql needs to change data on dimension and build from source.